# Javascript - Get a formated preview of files read with FileReader()?

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I tryed to implement a drag file functionality. I need a preview with the text of the file, in this case an HTML file. But when I insert the result of FileReader into the DOM, the preview loses all the line breaks and text-indent.

I tryed using jQuery .split() and inserting a `<br/>`, but still the text loses all the indentation.

```
for(var i = 0; i <files.length; i++){

    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(evt){
        var r = evt.target.result;

        r = r.replace(/>/g,'&gt; >');
        r = r.replace(/</g,'&lt;');
        r = r.split('>')

        var text="";
        for(var i =0; i<r.length; i++){
            r[i] = $.trim(r[i]);
            text += r[i]+'<br/>';
        }
        $('.drop-area').html(text);

    }
    reader.readAsText(files[i]);
}
```

Try dragging an HTML file here http://jsfiddle.net/gVZRU/2/

Is possible to solve that? Is there any other approach I can take to have this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to add [`white-space: pre-wrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to the style of the display box.

Multiple successive whitespace in an HTML source is always collapsed into a single output whitespace in the rendered content. The `white-space` CSS properties allows you to change this behavior, and the `pre` value says to treat whitespace as the [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag does (i.e., show all whitespace in the rendered result). `pre-wrap` is just like `pre`, but allows wrapping of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`.text` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to insert text. No need for escaping manually. To fix the display issue, don't try to insert `<br>` tags after every closing tag but just use appropriate CSS: [`white-space: pre-wrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).